# Given $\sigma(AB-BA) = \{0\}$, what can be said about $\sigma(A)$ and $\sigma(B)$?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory

Let $\mathcal H$ be a separable Hilbert space, and $\mathfrak B(\mathcal H)$ denote the algebra of bounded linear operators on $\mathcal H$. Furthermore, let $A,B \in \mathfrak B(\mathcal H)$ be two distinct operators. Given the spectrum $\sigma([A,B])$ of the commutator $[A,B] := AB-BA$, can we say anything about $\sigma(A)$ and $\sigma(B)$? In particular, I am interested in learning about $A,B$ (or their spectra) given $\sigma([A,B]) = \{0\}$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For every pair of non-empty compact subsets $W,W'\subset\mathbf{C}$ there exist commuting $A,B$ with spectra $W,W'$. Indeed choose $U,U'$ with spectra $W,W'$, then fix $t,t'\in W,W'$, and define $A=U\oplus t\mathrm{id}$, $B=t'\mathrm{id}\oplus U'$. So knowing that $\sigma([A,B])=\{0\}$ gives no information about the spectra of $A,B$.

Comment: Thanks! Can we associate an operator with every non-empty compact subset of $\Bbb C$? The choice of $U,U'$ is not clear. On a different note, it seems $\sigma([A,B]) = \{0\}$ gives no information about $A,B$ either?

Comment: Yes. Take a dense sequence $(t_n)$ in this compact set $U$ and take the diagonal operator with diagonal $(t_n)$. Then the spectrum is $U$.